# Can we make chat login much smoother?

Tags: feature-request, bug, chat, login, openid

Currently, when logging into chat, it takes a rather long process to get in. The global auth doesn't always seem to work, and I have to go through a ton of steps to get in:

First, I see this:

[image]

Then, I go to the login page, and get this:

[image]

I wait 20 seconds for something to happen, and it doesn't.

So, I click the "login" via SE button and reach here:

[image]

(obviously I'm logged in to some network site, but not on SE.com)

I use my openID, and am redirected here:

[image]

And I naturally click here:

[image]

Which takes me *back* here:

[image]

I click "login", and I am taken back here:

[image]

Which *finally* takes me here:

[image]

and logs me in:

[image]

There is generally another step involved after this -- I need to re-navigate back to where I started when I clicked "login". This is especially annoying

---

There are a bunch of problems here which I think need fixing.

- The OpenID login form on SE.com is not respecting the `returnurl`. This would save us the unnecessary step of going back and forth trying to reach the chat login link.
- It would be nice if chat login had its own returnURL so that after logging in the system redirects me to the page where I clicked "login"
- The global authentication shouldn't be breaking in the first place, I guess. It has happened a lot when I am on a phone or behind a proxy, but happens when I'm on a normal connection as well.
- Why can't chat.SE have an openID login form hosted on the same site itself? Why the complexity?

Could some/all of this be fixed/improved?

Comment: Chat login on phones has been rather unreliable at times for me, but I think that buggy browsers are mostly to blame for that. Add to that an instable connection, and it can get rather frustrating.

Comment: @MadScientist: Exactly. I don't mind if the auto login fails. But then  I shouldn't have to go through the same clicks _twice_ just because of a forgotten `returnurl`. And again, it probably would be better if it didn't depend on SE.com for a login.

Comment: I actually like the way Wikipedia handles login. When you log in, a bunch of images are loaded, and these images basically contain login tokens for other network sites and they manage to log you in to all sites in one go. (I don't exactly know how the per-language login is handled though. I can login to en.wikipedia and be automatically logged in to hi.wikipedia without any special image magic there)

Comment: I can't reproduce the broken return url on stackexchange.com. I just tried your steps, and after logging in to se.com via OpenID, I immediately got kicked back to chat -- logged in.

Comment: @balpha: Hm, looks like an issue with my HTTP proxy (not sure why it breaks on phones). I ran it through a tunnel and it showed a banner "Welcome, you have been logged in, you are now being redirected". Still, would it be possible to implement a direct login to chat.SE?